# Set image as desktop background without downloading it in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there any functionality within chrome or is there an extension available that allows image opened in chrome tab to be set as desktop background without actually downloading it, just like Firefox allows.

Comment: You do understand that you still download the file even with Firefox right?

Comment: I am not talking about downloading the image file..when an image is opened in a tab, how to set it as desktop background without actually downloading. This is possible in Firefox, if you are not aware  of it.

Comment: Stop trolling, Jesus. What OP means is to set wallpaper transparently with a click. Just like when you can open an image in Chrome, it doesn't tell you that it's storing a copy in temp.

Comment: What needs to be answered in order to tell what OP actually means is whether he does not want any image file stored on his computer when he sets it as background (in which case @Ramhound is right), or whether he just wants to be able to skip a step in setting a background image from the Chrome browser (in which case KalEl is right).

Comment: @music2myear The community “troll” also know as the community user, bumped this random question after 3 years

Comment: I know.........

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Desktop Wallpaper Tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20140901082555/http://www.digital-art-gallery.com/desktop-wallpaper) - there's a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/iehjagmekelocghcldjolleiolfkobge) for it that activates a tooltip. This will open up the image with the tool so you can set it as your wallpaper

Comment: The extension 'Set Image as Wallpaper' or something similar is exactly what I'm looking for. But sadly, the link as well the extension is down!

Comment: Strange, I expect this to be a core functionality...

Comment: App is no longer in the store; any alternatives?